# Sections in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, sections, wkinterfacetable

I am trying to create a table with sections having varying number of rows. I saw the solution given here [How to create sections in WKInterfaceTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803813/how-to-create-sections-in-wkinterfacetable) and tried it as follows:

```
tableView.setRowTypes(rowTypes);
for q in 0...rowTypes.count-1 {
    if (rowTypes[q] == "teamSection") {
        let row = tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(q) as? teamSection;
    }
    else {
        let row = tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(q) as? teamRow;
    }
}
```

I have my `rowTypes` as follows:

```
let rowTypes = ["teamSection", "teamRow", "teamSection", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow", "teamRow"];
```

I was expecting 11 rows but am only getting 9 which are all of the `teamRow` type and none of the `teamSection`.
Can anyone spot what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `teamSection` isn't a valid row type. Are you sure you've set up the table in the storyboard with two rows and set the identifier correctly for one of them as "teamSection"?

Comment: indeed `teamSection` wasn't a valid `rowType`. I didn't know I had to setup only a SINGLE table with 2 rows. I used 2 different tables and linked them to the same outlet. I have deleted one table and moved the row into the other and it worked.
Thanks man.